# I cannot epollctl() a pipe - I get Bad Address

Tags: epoll

I am trying to write a function that will make me break a epoll_wait().

I have

```
void SocketSystem::epollBreakWait(int epoll)
{
    if (epoll == ERROR_CODE)
        return;

    int selfpipe[PIPE_PAIR];

    if (pipe(selfpipe) < 0)
        std::cout << "Error on self pipe." << std::endl;

    if (::epoll_ctl(epoll, EPOLL_CTL_ADD, selfpipe[0], NULL) == ERROR_CODE)
        std::cout <<  "Error breaking epoll." << std::endl;

    int temp = 0;
    ::write(selfpipe[1], &temp, sizeof(temp));   
}
```

But when I run it I get error (-1) and errno = Bad address.
Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

How do you call `epoll_wait` itself? And I suppose you have to provide non null `struct epoll_event` to `epoll_ctl`

Answer (score 0):

Spell it?

I have tried to put in a non null epoll_event to epoll_ctl as you suggested, and that seemed to fix the problem.